# Problem: Java.util.date does not allow duplicate date value in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, mapping, java.util.date

I have tried to create a table that includes some information like `id`, `date`, `staff`, and `provider` to perform a CRUD. When I add a date with java.util.date and `@Jsonformat`, it does not let me insert a duplicate value.
For example, when I insert a date "25-01-1996", hence, I cannot insert that day again.
It said that:"**ERROR:duplicate key value violates unique constraint Detail: Key(date)=(2107-01-25 07:00:00) already exists**".
Then, I have tried many ways with java.util.date like custom a serializer or deserializer but it has not yet worked.
Here is my model:

```java
        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @Column(name="date", nullable = false, unique = false)
        //@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
        //@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
        //@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
        @GeneratedValue
        private Date date;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="staff_id")
        private Staff staff;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="provider_id")
        private Provider provider;
```

Here is the Serializer and Deserializer:

```java
    {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
                String DateSerializer = dateFormat.format(date);
                jsonGenerator.writeString(DateSerializer);
    }
}
```

```java
    {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)){
            try {
                Date date = dateFormat.parse(jsonParser.getText().toString());
                return date;
            } catch (ParseException e) {

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The another version that I have tried:

```java
    private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>(){
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue()
        {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        }
    };

    public String formatIt(Date date)
    {
        return formatter.get().format(date);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that in the database also the `date` not marked as a unique index

Comment: @Vishnu  Thanks! I have a look at my database but seems it doesn't have any unique data

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use the `@GeneratedValue` annotation for a field that is not [entity identifier](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-simple-generated) (annotated by the  `@Id` annotation).
2. You should use `@Temporal` annotation with `java.util.Date` to specify the `TemporalType`.

So, you should correct your model in the following way:

```java
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name="date", nullable = false, unique = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private Date date;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="staff_id")
private Staff staff;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="provider_id")
private Provider provider;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the **full stack** of your exception.

Comment: I tried many way to custom my date serializer and now it worked! Btw thank you so much my friend!